# TYPO3 sys_language_mode = strict still get me the record with "Default" language

Tags: typo3

Why does `sys_language_mode = strict` get me the record with Default language if the specified record is not existing for other languages?

The expected behavior is to not show anything if the record is not existing for the specified language.

The `config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated` which says that "Fetch records from the default language and overlay them with translations. If some record is not translated it will not be shown."

Comment: You've got config.sys_language_mode = strict including the config. right?

Comment: yes, including the confg.

Comment: can you please add your language config typoscript here. so we can check this configuration.

Comment: Also try to use config.sys_language_overlay = 0.