# config.sys_language_mode = strict doesn't get the files from a record which is set to "All Languages"

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, fal

I don't get the files from a record which is set to "All Languages" with the following `config`:

```
config.sys_language_mode = strict
config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
```

The record is just set to "All Languages". I get this record on every language, but the issue is that the files are not attached to this record. 
They are existing only for the Default language.

**UPDATE**

After a bit of reasearch i just found this https://forge.typo3.org/issues/63092

Maybe somebody has a solution for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 sys\_language\_mode = strict still get me the record with "Default" language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082382/typo3-sys-language-mode-strict-still-get-me-the-record-with-default-language)

Comment: it's not duplicated, this is a different problem - please checkout this link https://forge.typo3.org/issues/63092